# Why do I fail to create a window with GLFW on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glfw

I'll be glad if someone could please tell me what is the issue here:

```
int main() {

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "window", NULL, NULL);

}
```

Comment: On which OS are you running this application ?

Comment: What do you do once you have the window? Do you enter an event loop of sorts? Maybe the window is created just fine, but disappears immediately.

Comment: @thomas no, it just says "Failed to create a GLFW window", like I just told it to when it fails

Comment: By the way, don't do `glfwInit() == false`, as it returns an int. Just do `!glfwInit()`.

Comment: @Thomas it still fails

Comment: From the docs: "Windows: Window creation will fail if the Microsoft GDI software OpenGL implementation is the only one available." So this might be a driver issue.

Comment: @Thomas I thought about it too but my driver is updated, it may be the gpu..

Comment: Have you tried turning off some of the hints to see if you can get a window if you don't specify Core Profile 3.3 and samples?

Comment: @jherico wow ty, I deleted those 4 lines and it work, but the question if I need them? what they even do?

Comment: @Jherico wow ty, I deleted those 4 lines and it work, but the question if I need them? what they even do?

Comment: You should try adding them back individually and see which one was causing the problem (although the major/minor version items should be added as a pair.  It's likely that your driver simply doesn't support a specific OpenGL version, or the core profile specifically (although I think 3.3 requires core profile support, so it's probably a matter of both).  Or it's possible that your card doesn't support multisampling and GLFW isn't finding a suitable fallback pixel format (although it should since it's only a hint, so that might be a bug in GLFW).

Comment: @Jherico hey I found out that it was this line: glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there is an issues with your OpenGL drivers on Windows.

Try to check and update your OpenGL drivers :

- Install an OpenGL viewer, such as the [GLview](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/download.php) utility, to view the OpenGL version installed on your machine.
- For Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7, open the viewer to find the version and driver version under OpenGL running on your computer.
- Click the “Check for updated drivers” link to identify if any driver updates are necessary.

Excerpts taken from this [website](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/03/15/what-version-of-opengl-do-i-have-and-do-i-have-the-latest-drivers-for-my-system/).