# glfw does not create a window

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

when i create a simple glfw window and set these two flags:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

the window will be NULL and i have no idea why.
The window will be created if those two things are not called.

Here is the code Below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        cout << "glfw did not initialize!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GL_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 300, "ARoo", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        cout << "window == null" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

im using visual studi comunity 2015, windows 8.1 x64(glfw and glew are x32)
my video drivers are up to date.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23702679/2050745) . Maybe you have use wrong version.

Answer (score 4):

The problem could be related to the requested OpenGL profile.

You can have diagnostic messages about what's happening, you just need to set a callback, which can be done before `glfwInit()`:

```
static void glfwError(int id, const char* description)
{
  std::cout << description << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  glfwSetErrorCallback(&glfwError);
  glfwInit();
  ...
```